# Saving UTF-8 CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I've been struggling with this, and have read numerous threads, but I can't seem to get this working. I need to save a UTF-8 CSV file.

Firstly, here's my super-simple approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import sys
import codecs

f = codecs.open("output.csv", "w", "utf-8-sig")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
cells = ["hello".encode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".encode("utf-8"), "你好".encode("utf-8")]
writer.writerow(cells)
```

That results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./makesimplecsv.py", line 10, in <module>
    cells = ["hello".encode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".encode("utf-8"), "你好".encode("utf-8")]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've also tried using the UnicodeWriter class that's listed in the Python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import sys
import codecs
import cStringIO

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

f = codecs.open("output.csv", "w", "utf-8-sig")
writer = UnicodeWriter(f)
cells = ["hello".encode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".encode("utf-8"), "你好".encode("utf-8")]
writer.writerow(cells)
```

That results in the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./makesimplecsvwithunicodewriter.sh", line 40, in <module>
    cells = ["hello".encode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".encode("utf-8"), "你好".encode("utf-8")]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I thought I'd gone through the checklist of things I've found in other similar questions:

- My file has an encoding statement.
- I'm opening the file for writing with UTF-8.
- I'm encoding the individual strings in UTF-8 before I pass them to the CSV writer.
- I've tried with and without adding a UTF-8 BOM, but that doesn't seem to make any difference, or indeed be critical, from what I've read.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing **encoded** byte strings to your CSV file. There is little point in doing this when you are expecting Unicode objects.

Don't encode, **decode**:

```
cells = ["hello".decode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".decode("utf-8"), "你好".decode("utf-8")]
```

or use `u'...'` unicode string literals:

```
cells = [u"hello", u"nǐ hǎo", u"你好"]
```

You cannot use a `codecs.open()` file object with the Python 2 `csv` module. Either use the `UnicodeWriter` approach (with a regular file object) and pass in Unicode objects, or encode your cells to byte strings and use the `csv.writer()` object directly (again with a regular file object), as that's what the `UnicodeWriter` does; pass encoded byte strings to the `csv.writer()` object.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this working based on your feedback. I used the UnicodeWriter approach, and switched the encode() calls to decode(), and I used the standard open() function to get the file object for writing. I'm going to update the question with the solution that works for future reference.

Comment: @antun: If you feel the need then add your own solution as a new answer; the question should remain just a question.

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Thanks to the accepted answer I was able to get this working. Here is the full working example for future reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import sys
import codecs
import cStringIO

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

f = open("output.csv", "w")

writer = UnicodeWriter(f)
cells = ["hello".decode("utf-8"), "nǐ hǎo".decode("utf-8"), "你好".decode("utf-8")]
writer.writerow(cells)
```