# How to Handle Special Characters When Exporting to CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

My Python code pulls data from a website and exports the result to a CSV.
The code breaks when a foreign letter is detected and not all data get downloaded.

This is the error I am getting:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f6f5' in position 91: character maps to "undefined"
```

An example would be when a row contains russian alphabet or special characters such as the number sign # or a *.

This is my code that exports data to CSV. Please let me know how I can fix this error:

```
# save it to csv
  with open('links.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_out:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
# Create the header rows
  csv_writer.writerow(['url', 'title','price','location'])
  for row in data:
      csv_writer.writerow([str(row['link']),str(row['title']),str(row['price']),
      str(row['location'])])
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959214/saving-utf-8-csv-with-python

Comment: Use `open('links.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')` when opening your file.

Comment: @enzo Still returns an error: AttributeError: module 'unicodedata' has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Working now thank you @enzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running on Windows? If so, try specifying the file encoding when opening the file, e.g.

```
open('links.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
```